# jQuery shows that two same values are not same

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a chatbox with jQuery and php. Everything works, however i have one problem. I made such function for scrolling down

```
function scrolld() {
    $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight);
}
```

and it really works. Problem is when i am trying to use this function to scroll down and see latest messages. I am trying to use this function JUST when there is new messages, but it scrolls down every second... There is that function:

```
function update() {
    $.post("../../getinfo.php", { token:token2},
        function (result) {
                $('.pirmas').text($('#messages').html()); //messages now
                $('.antras').text(result);//messages from database
                if($('.pirmas').text() != $('.antras').text())
                { //when they are not equal (there is new message)
                    scrolld();
                }
                $('#messages').html(result);
        });
    window.setTimeout(update, 1000);
}
```

How to make it scroll just when i have new messages? Because i tryed and saw that jquery shows that variables that are SAME are not equal (checked with php and they were equal) Can anyone help me? :) Thanks!

Comment: Should be pretty easy to pop this code and an HTML sample into a demo at http://jsfiddle.net. That would be helpful.

Comment: Please make all lowercase and trim the space before compare.

Comment: thanks for everything, now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

could be a whitespace issue.. extra spaces...

```
if($('.pirmas').text().trim() != $('.antras').text().trim()){...}
```